# Creating a new layer for free space between existing layers

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, merge

How can I create a new layer that will only show the 'free space' between the raster and vector layers that are currently on my map?

Will I have to merge my existing raster and vector layers and use some kind of inverse selection tool? If so could someone explain how?

[image: Image of Pembrokeshire with raster and vector layers]

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a big polygon that covers your whole area of interest and compute difference (big polygon) - (union of your features).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where is the compute difference (big polygon) tool?

Comment: There is a search option in the processing toolbox. Write "difference" into the search box.

Comment: @Olivia I believe user30184's suggestion was to use the `union` tool to combine the features, then use the `difference` tool to subtract the union from the big polygon. That should work for vector layers, not for raster data. If some of your data is raster, please [edit] your question and explain which layers are vector and which are raster, as it's not clear from your screenshot.